# Non-separable linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to motivate the theory of $C_0$-semigroups to someone, and the following question was asked:

> What is an example of a non-separable linear PDE?

Preferably a simple homogeneous one.

Comment: Maybe a non-homogeneous modification of a homogeneous equation suffices?

Comment: Yes, perhaps, but are there homogeneous ones?

Comment: Most variable coefficient PDEs cannot be separated. Separability is very closely tied to symmetries of the coefficients, so as long as you cannot choose a coordinate system in which the coefficients are independent of one (or several) of the variables, you cannot make it separable.

Comment: On the other hand, to use a $C_0$ semigroup to solve an evolutionary PDE presupposes time independence of the coefficients. So at least the time-variable is separable. If you want to break *that* you'd have to use a $C_0$ semi-groupoid instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my comments above on some general ideas. For specific examples, perhaps a good starting point would be L. P. Eisenhart, "Enumeration of potentials for which one-particle Schrodinger equations are separable," Phys. Rev. 74, 87-89 (1948). So just take an arbitrary potential function $V(x)$ that is *not* in Eisenhart's list, and consider the Schroedinger equation

$$ [-i \partial_t + \triangle + V(x)]\psi(t,x) = 0$$

This is Linear, homogeneous, and aside from the trivial separability of the $t$ variable, satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Yes, a nice one.